# How to add a WordPress Nonce for this form to avoid CSRF

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, nonce

Here is the Form and I would like to add a WordPress nonce to it:

```
          <form action="" method="post">
            <label>Enter your email address:</label> <input id="email" type="email" name="yourmail" value="<?php echo $current_user->user_email; ?>" disabled="disabled">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Test">
          </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Reference to a form field [WP Nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field)

```
<form method="post">
   <!-- some inputs here ... -->
   <?php wp_nonce_field( 'name_of_my_action', 'name_of_nonce_field' ); ?>
</form>
```